# Listing of files between two timestamp

Tags: timestamps

I want to list down the files between two timestamp. But I can not use newer or newermt command as it doesn't support these tokens.

Is there any other way to achieve this? Else I have to write too much of coding .

Input

Code:

Dec 01 02:02
 Dec 02 05:07

Comment: I assume you are talking about the `-newermt` predicate for the `find` command. Why can't use use it? That's exactly what it's for!

Answer (score 5):

`find /directory -type f -newermt "2014-10-08 10:17:00" ! -newermt "2014-10-08 10:53:00"`